# Python: what is the best way to read and command different devices at the same time?

Tags: python, multithreading

I use a Raspberry Pi with a BrickPi to control LEGO motors. I want to take input from a gamepad, like the logitech F310, and run motors based off of the joystick input. I have found that getting input from gamepads requires blocking, like `for event in get_gamepad():` where it constantly checks for input and will not move on unless it gets input. Also, my motors require the command `BrickPiUpdateValues()` every moment to run. So I need to do two things at once, but the gamepad blocks the motor update.

In this short program that worked for me, I used threading, but **is there a better way to complete this task, or a way to better my code?** Also, Ctrl-C wouldn't exit the gamepad thread, even when I tried to use `try` and `except` to allow a Keyboard Interrupt. **What is a good way to exit threads?** `join` didn't work well because it waits for the thread to finish.

```
from inputs import get_gamepad
from BrickPi import *
import threading

BrickPiSetup()
BrickPi.MotorEnable[PORT_A] = 1 #enable motor A

quitting = False #make the variable

def gamepad(): #the thread to read the gamepad
    while True:
        for event in get_gamepad(): #waits for input
            if event.code == "ABS_Y":
                BrickPi.MotorSpeed[PORT_A] = event.state / 128 #use joystick input to decide speed
            elif event.code == "BTN_MODE": #quit thread, program will quit as well
                global quitting
                quitting = True
                return

gamepad = threading.Thread(target = gamepad)
gamepad.start() #start reading the gamepad

while True:
    BrickPiUpdateValues() #actually run the motor
    if quitting == True: #full quit, triggered by mode button
        sys.exit()
```